# Read multiple csv files into separate dataframes loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading multiple CSV files and reformatting them. I have developed this code which reads a single file. However, I am wondering if I can loop the process to read multiple files into separate dataframes and then work on those dataframes to format and rewrite a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

station_id = 'id.csv'
input_file = 'filename.txt'
unformatted = 'C:/Users/....../Unformatted/'
formatted = 'C:/....../Formatted/'


print(f'\nReading data file: {input_file}.')
fields = {
    'Timestamp': 'timestamp',
 #  'Sample Point Name': 'station_name',
 #  'Sample Point Name Description': 'station_description',
 #  'Start Date':'state_date',
    'PM10 (1h) Validated': 'PM_1h_10_ug_m3',
    'PM10 Validated' :'PM_10_ug_m3',
 #  'PM2.5 (1h) Final': 'pm_25',
 #  'PM2.5 Final': 'pm2.5_ug_m3'
 }


df = pd.read_table(unformatted+input_file, usecols=fields.keys(), sep='\t', encoding = 'utf-16')

df.rename(columns=fields, inplace=True)


df.loc[:, 'timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)

df['date'] = df['timestamp']
df['time'] = df['timestamp']


df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda z: z.strftime('%H%M'))

df['Date_Time'] = df['date'] +' '+ df['time']

df.drop(['timestamp', 'date', 'time'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df[['Date_Time', 'PM_1h_10_ug_m3', 'PM_10_ug_m3']]

availability_PM_1h = df['PM_1h_10_ug_m3'].count()/df['Date_Time'].count()*100

availability_PM_10_min = df['PM_10_ug_m3'].count()/df['Date_Time'].count()*100


#Check for nan values

PM10_nan = df['PM_10_ug_m3'].isnull().sum()
PM10_1h_nan = df['PM_1h_10_ug_m3'].isnull().sum()

print('Count of PM10 NaN: ' + str(PM10_nan))
print('Count of PM10_1h NaN: ' + str(PM10_1h_nan))

df.to_csv(formatted+station_id, index=False)
```

Comment: Are the operations done on every CSV file same , and does this code if repeated suffice ?

Comment: Yes. The operations would be same on every CSV file and if we repeat this code, it will do the job. All the files and output are identical. Just need to each CSV with new filename.

Answer (score 0):

Say you wrap the whole code for whatever you want to do with a single file in a function: `read_single_df(filepath)`. Then your code for multiple files will look like:

```py
# filepaths: this is the variable to store the filepaths to all files as a list

import os
import pandas as pd
from typing import List

def read_csv(filepath: str, *args, **kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Reads a single csv file and processes it before returning 
       a `pandas.DataFrame`.
    """
    # your logic for a single file goes here 
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.abspath(filepath))

    # further processing steps for a single file...
    # ...
    return df

# define a list to store dataframes
dfs: List[pd.DataFrame] = []

# run loop to read and store dataframes in the list: dfs
for filepath in filepaths:
    dfs.append(read_csv(filepath))
```

Now you can call each dataframe from the list `dfs` as `dfs[0]`, `dfs[1]`, etc. and apply further processing downstream.

### Some suggested improvements to your code:

The following line is all you need instead of those six lines.

```py
df['Date_Time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H%M')
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it is taking filepath as "C", hence returning me an error. The error is [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CWBAQRT022.txt'.

Comment: First try `pd.read_csv(filepath).head()` and see if that works for you or not. If that does not work, I am surprised why did not try that first? Quite obviously you are then stuck at resolving the path in Windows. You would need to use `import os; filepath = os.path.abspath(filepath)`. One more thing: in windows your path should look like this: `filepath = r"C:\\Your\\Path\\To\\File.csv"` instead of `filepath = "C:/Your/Path/To/File.csv"`.